# Undefined function 'qquadrature' for input arguments of type 'double'

Tags: matlab, double, undefined

I'm a new user of Matlab, can you please help:

I have the following code in an .M file:

```
`% free vibration of non-prismatic Euler beams with or without axial load
%using differential quadrature method
clc;
ne=50;
n=ne+1;
nn=2*n;
no=4;
m=zeros(n,1);
x=zeros(n,1);
xi=zeros(n,1);
c=zeros(n,n,no);
d=zeros(n+4,n+4);
e=zeros(n+4,n+4);
z=zeros(n+4,1);
f=zeros(n+4,1);
alp=zeros(n,n);
bet=zeros(n,n);
zz=zeros(n,1);
ki=zeros(n,n);
eta=zeros(n,n);
const=1.0;
l=12;
ymod=200e09;
rho=7800;
format long;
for i=1:n
    xi(i)=0.5*(1-cos((i-1)*pi/ne));
    %mi(i)=0.000038*(1-xi(i)^2/2);
    ar(i)=1/rho;
    mi(i)=0.000038;
    ki(i,i)=ymod*mi(i);
end
c=qquadrature(xi,n,no);
%c = harquadrature(xi,n,no)
for i = 1:n
   alp(i,i) = 0;
   bet(i,i) = 0;
    for j = 1:n
        alp(i,i) = alp(i,i)+c(i,j,1)*ki(j,j)/l;
        bet(i,i) = bet(i,i)+c(i,j,2)*ki(j,j)/l^2;
    end
end
d=zeros(n+4,n+4);
% free vibration of the beam
% axial load on the beam t=+ if it is compressive t=- if it is tensile
% weight of the beam / unit length
t=520895.0;
d(1:n,1:n)=2.0*alp*c(:,:,3)/l^3+bet*c(:,:,2)/l^2+ki*c(:,:,4)/l^4+eta+t*c(:,:,2)/l^2;
% boundary conditions
% clamped - free
% d(n+1,1)=1.0;
% d(n+2:n+2,1:n)=alp(n,n)*c(n,1:n,2)/l^2+ki(n,n)*c(n,1:n,3)/l^3+t*c(n,1:n,1)/l;
% d(n+3:n+3,1:n)=c(1,1:n,1)/l;
% d(n+4:n+4,1:n)=ki(n,n)*c(n,1:n,2)/l^2;
% d(1,n+1)=1.0;
% for i=1:n
% d(i,n+2)=d(n+2,i);
% d(i,n+3)=d(n+3,i);
% d(i,n+4)=d(n+4,i);
% end
% pinned - pinned
d(n+1,1)=1.0;
d(n+2:n+2,1:n)=ki(n,n)*c(n,1:n,2)/l^2;
d(n+3:n+3,1:n)=ki(1,1)*c(1,1:n,2)/l^2;
d(n+4,n)=1.0;
d(n,n+4)=1.0;
d(1,n+1)=1.0;
d(n+4,n)=1.0;
for i = 1:n
    d(i,n+2)=d(n+2,i);
        d(i,n+3)=d(n+3,i);
end
e=zeros(n+4,n+4);
for i=1:n
 e(i,i)=rho*ar(i);
end
z=d\e;
[ev,euv]=eig(z);
for i=1:n
zz(z)=ev(i,5);
end
omega=sqrt(1/euv(5,5));
sprintf(' natural frequency\n')
omega;
figure(1);
plot(xi,zz)
xlabel(' x/L ')
ylabel(' z')
title (' fundamental mode shape ')`
```

I have stored this file (Untitled.M) in the normal Matlab path, and therefore I'm assuming that Matlab will read the function when it's starting and that this function therefore should be available to use.
Then I am trying to run this single M-files.
But "Undefined function 'qquadrature' for input arguments of type 'double'" message appears..
Can somebody show me where's the problem and how ti fix it?
Thankyou..

Comment: is the function you're trying to use called `qquadrature` or `quadrature`?

Comment: Have a look at how matlab's search path [works](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/path.html)